# how to break from the function?

Tags: c

I have the void function `void isVaraRegistered` that should check for existent numbers in the array that are introduced as `varanummer` in regVaror. If the introduced number already exists it should break from the regVaror function. I am not sure how to do it. How to set isVaraRegistered to true or false or any combination in fact. Please help!

```
     //lager program lab 
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <stdbool.h>

 #define DEPOSIT 10
 #define WORDLENGTH 30
 #define MAX 10

 struct varor{
     int varunummer;
     char namn[WORDLENGTH];
     int lagersaldo; 
 };
 typedef struct varor Vara;

 Vara createVara(int varunummer, char namn[], int lagersaldo){
     Vara v;
     v.varunummer=varunummer;
     strcpy(v.namn, namn);
     v.lagersaldo=lagersaldo;
     return v;
 }
void isVaraRegistered(Vara reg[], int varunummer){
    for(int n=0; n<MAX; n++){
        if(reg[n].varunummer==varunummer) {
            printf("\nError! Varunummer finns redan!\n\n");

        }
        break;
    }   
}

 void regVaror( Vara reg[], int *pNrOfVaror){

     char confirm;
     char namn[WORDLENGTH],
          tmp[WORDLENGTH];
     int varunummer, lagersaldo;
     printf("\nÄr du säkert att du vill registrera nya varor?\n1: Ja - (fortsätt)\n2: Nej - (gå tillbaka till menyn)\n");
     scanf(" %c%*c", &confirm);// %*c för att inte skippa raden dvs skipppa ange varunummer
     switch(confirm){
     case '1': 
     do{
         printf("Ange varunummer:");
         gets(tmp); 
         varunummer=atoi(tmp);
         isVaraRegistered(reg,varunummer);


         printf("Ange namn:");
         gets(namn);
         printf("Ange lagersaldo:");
         gets(tmp);
         lagersaldo=atoi(tmp); 
         reg[*pNrOfVaror]=createVara(varunummer,namn,lagersaldo);
         (*pNrOfVaror)++;
         printf("\nRegristrera mer varor?\n1: Ja - (fortsätt)\n2: Nej - (gå tillbaka till menyn)\n");
         scanf(" %c%*c", &confirm);
     }while(confirm=='1');

     case '2': break;

     }
 }


 int main(){
     int run=1;
     Vara vRegister[MAX];
     int nrOfVaror=0;
     while(run){
        char choice;
        printf("\n\t\tMeny - Lager Program\n\n\
        (1) Regristrera nya varor\n\b\b\b\b\
        (2) Skriva ut alla varor\n\
        (3) Söka efter varor\n\
        (4) Ändra lagersaldot för varor\n\
        (5) Sortera varor\n\
        (6) Avregristrera varor\n\
        (7) Avsluta programmet\n");
        scanf(" %c%*c", &choice);

        if(choice=='1') regVaror(vRegister, &nrOfVaror);
        else if(choice=='7') run=0;


     }
     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: To immediately exit a void function, just execute a bare `return` statement, i.e. `return;`

Comment: @dasblinkenlight  this is not working, it just shows the error msg and then keeps going with the rest of the code in regVaror

Comment: @TomKarzes this is not working, it just shows the error msg and then keeps going with the rest of the code in regVaror

Comment: Your compiler is working fine. The `return` statement works just fine. Post your actual code and we'll be able to tell you what you did wrong.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker DONE

Comment: I see no `return` in the code you posted.

Comment: Why do you have a for loop with an unconditional break in it?

Comment: @christian-gibbons Because he wants to quit when the number is found. A structure approach is the better way though as with my answer.

Comment: Personally, I think that naming a function `isBlah(...)` that returns `void` is confusing for the programmer/maintainer. In the posted code, there is no communication between `isVaraRegistered` and `regVaror`. It only runs once through the loop, then breaks out and continues in `regVaror` without regard to what `isVaraRegistered` does.

Comment: Instead of trying to exit one function from another function (don't use `isVaraRegistered` to try to exit out of `regVaror`), return a value from `isVaraRegistered` and check that value in `regVaror`. If the returned value is not what you want, then use a `break` statement in the while loop part of `regVaror` to leave that block, or a `return` statement to leave the entire `regVaror` function.

Comment: @StephenYork that would involve a conditional break.  That is, break on the condition that the number is found.  But that is not the case here.  The break is unconditional and will be reached every iteration of the loop (well, there will only ever BE one iteration since it'll break out of the loop).

Comment: @StephenYork so what am I supposed to do here?

Comment: Have a look at the answer I've provided. The for loop has a condition clause which must be true in order for the loop to continue so I've added a found == 0 condition which will not be satisfied after the number is as it will be incremented to 1 therefore the loop will stop running and the function returns.  
I still do think that the return type should be int and end the end of the function put `return found;`

Answer (score 0):

A straight return will do it, but I tend to lean towards a more controlled exit in exceptional situations and let the function run through.  Obviously there are scenarios where it's fine to have multiple returns but I try to keep it to a guard at the beginning and maybe a couple of special circumstances prior to finishing.  But I wouldn't **return** from inside a loop.  Just makes me feel dirty :)

So in your situation I would actually break as you are doing already which will return anyway... Your code is fine.  But I'd lean towards this approach:

```
void isVaraRegistered(Vara reg[], int varunummer){
    int found = 0;
    for(int n=0; found == 0 && n<MAX; n++){
        if(reg[n].varunummer==varunummer) {
            printf("\nError! Varunummer finns redan!\n\n");//existing error msg
            found++;
        }
    }   
}
```

Note that this is just a personal coding style thing. Moving over to C# a few years ago thee was a push in our company to standardise and write a certain way and this sort of controlled execution of letting the full function run through was preferred.

--- Edit:
I was responding to the original code, you've updated since I started responding.

Incidentally, should should set int as your return type and return 1 or 0 indicating yes or no given the name of the function and return the `found` variable I introduced. Then where the function is called respond accordingly....and take out the printf as the function itself has one responsibility which is to answer the question 'isVaraRegistered?'. Any user I/O should be done outside this function.